# MEF on Compact Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, mef

Can Microsoft's Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) be used with the Compact Framework edition of .Net (any version)?

If so, can it be used on Windows Mobile 6.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, MEF relies on the full .NET framework. .NETCF is only a small subset and therefore MEF cannot be used.

I found an alternative on Codeplex: http://pocketmef.codeplex.com/releases/view/37780 But I don't know anything about this project.